# ASP.NET: Add ASPX/View Comments visible only in code editor (not sent to browser)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

is there a way to do good commenting in an ASPX page (actually an ASP.NET MVC View - but it's the same thing, HTML content) without having all those comments sent to the client browser?

I like good commenting but I don't want to send all those lines of comments to visitors. Any way to prevent that (different comment tag or workaround?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<%-- Server side comment --%>
```